# What is the default color of the UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I'd like the text in my selected cell to be the same color as the UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark accessory. Is this stored somewhere as a constant? If not, what is its value as RGB?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no constant defined, measuring within IB (StoryBoard) results to #213D71.

[image]

Measurement done using ColorPicker with the extension [Hex Color Picker](http://wafflesoftware.net/hexpicker/).

Comment: Thanks! FWIW, I converted hex #213D71 to R(0.129412), G(0.239216), B(0.443137).